# How to check .Net framework installed on Windows

Tags: .net

How to check .Net framework installed on Windows using power shell or any programmatically? I have been checking the registry key value in path **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP** and referring to below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed.

Recently figured out way to get .Net framework version installed using PowerShell.

Comment: Console.WriteLine( $"Version: {Environment.Version}" )

Answer (score 0):

Use below given PowerShell to get the .Net Framework version installed on Windows:

How to check .Net framework installed on Windows

```
gci ‘HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP’ -recurse | gp -name Version -EA 0 | where { $_.PSChildName -match ‘^(?!S)\p{L}’} | select PSChildName, Version
```